# Objects in a scene have their own light

Tags: objects, lighting

I'm working on an ambitious project, using a lot of tools and features I've never used before.

I'm nearing the end and I'm trying to figure out my lighting. I watched some videos on lighting in blender but for some reason my objects, the axes, are not being affected much by the light sources I add. In fact they seems to be their own independent light source in both Eevee and Cycles. I've turned the entire background black and yet they still remain visible in the render preview. They don't have an emission tied to them. They are using nodes for image texture, subsurface scattering, color ramp, and mix shader.

I know I've made a few mistakes during this process but I have no idea what is causing them to be lit like this. [image: Camera view of the axes]

Comment: have you tried adding an HDRI ?

Comment: hello could you please pack the images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Are your nodes connected through a shader (BSDF), or are they connected directly to the material output? That looks like un-shaded outputs to me.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, have you tried to increase the power of the lights? Something like this?
[image: This shows that the power is 32000 Watts]

Sometimes, if the scene is big, more power is needed. Also, clicking on the **Preview** helps in determining the light strength. HTH

Answer (score -1):

### Here's 3 things to try:

**1. Turn the World Strength to 0.**

In the World tab in the Properties panel (or in your Background Node in the World node editor), set the *Strength* to 0 instead of 5.

**2. Make sure ALL lights are deleted/hidden.**

You can press H to temporarily hide an object.

**3. Be sure that your models are not using Emission shaders.**

Emission shaders are a type of shader that acts as a light source. Check that you're not using any Emission nodes in your materials.